# Using Anko Layouts in Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I have created the following layout:

```
class ExploreUI<T> : AnkoComponent<T> {

    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<T>): View {

        return with(ui) {
            frameLayout {
                val loadingIndicator = include<View>(R.layout.loading_indicator)

                val content = nestedScrollView {
                    isFillViewport = true
                    visibility = View.GONE

                    verticalLayout {

                        /** New Releases */
                        themedTextView(R.string.new_releases, theme = R.style.DarkThemeHeaderText) {
                            id = R.id.releasesHeader
                        }.lparams {
                            padding = dip(10)
                        }.apply {

                        }

                        val releasesRecycler = recyclerView {
                        }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)

                        include<View>(R.layout.show_more)

                        /** Recommended playlists */
                        themedTextView(R.string.recommended_playlists, theme = R.style.DarkThemeHeaderText) {
                            id = R.id.releasesHeader
                        }.lparams {
                            padding = dip(10)
                        }.apply {

                        }

                        val playlistsRecycler = recyclerView {
                        }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)

                        include<View>(R.layout.show_more)

                        /** Recently played */
                        themedTextView(R.string.recently_played, theme = R.style.DarkThemeHeaderText) {
                            id = R.id.releasesHeader
                        }.lparams {
                            padding = dip(10)
                        }.apply {

                        }

                        val recentsRecycler = recyclerView {
                        }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)

                        include<View>(R.layout.show_more)

                        /** Popular artists */
                        themedTextView(R.string.popular_artists, theme = R.style.DarkThemeHeaderText) {
                            id = R.id.releasesHeader
                        }.lparams {
                            padding = dip(10)
                        }.apply {

                        }

                        val artistsRecycler = recyclerView {
                        }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)

                        include<View>(R.layout.show_more)

                        /** Recommended tracks */
                        themedTextView(R.string.most_recommeneded, theme = R.style.DarkThemeHeaderText) {
                            id = R.id.releasesHeader
                        }.lparams {
                            padding = dip(10)
                        }.apply {

                        }

                        val recommendedTracksRecycler = recyclerView {
                        }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)

                        include<View>(R.layout.show_more)

                        /** All time hits */
                        themedTextView(R.string.based_on_your_listening, theme = R.style.DarkThemeHeaderText) {
                            id = R.id.releasesHeader
                        }.lparams {
                            padding = dip(10)
                        }.apply {

                        }

                        val hitsRecycler = recyclerView {
                        }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)

                        include<View>(R.layout.show_more)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I then inflate the layout on `onCreateView` as follows:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
            ExploreUI().createView(AnkoContext.Companion.create(activity as AppCompatActivity, this))
```

The problem I have is accessing the components defined in my UI class. How do I reference them from my Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is to expose the values you're interested in as properties.

However, what I recommend doing is to use a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) so your fragment isn't talking directly to your views. The fragments role is to bind the ViewModel to the views.